# Data transport optimization with Google cloud endpoints

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, serialization, google-cloud-endpoints

I am sending a `List<Item>` from google app engine(java) to javascript through google cloud endpoints.

`Item`:

```
public class Item implements Serializable { 

    private String item1;   
    private Integer item2;
    private String item3;   
    //(...) item (4-39)
    private String item40;  

   //Constructor, Getters, setters, +functions

}
```

In javascript I am receiving the data with the following structure for each Item:

```
{item1:"v1",item2:"v2"}
```

Also at the end of each object I receive a lot of data that I don't understand why is sent.

[image]

The '?' data is not my defined functions. I think that it is Serializable object functions, but I don't understand why is sent.

I need to send data in this format: `{"v1","v2"}`  instead of `{item1:"v1",item2:"v2", a lot of functions}` to reduce the size of data.

I think to solve the problem sending the data in `List<String>` of java.

But it is a bit complicated and "ugly" because for example some properties of the `Item` object are structured objects.

Is there a way described in google cloud endpoints to send data this way?

Is there any way to set endpoints only send the "necessary" data?

Comment: {"v1","v2"} is not valid JSON. So this is not possible. It's unclear to me what you view as unnecessary. Functions are not actually sent from the API server, they are created when the JSON string is parsed.

Comment: I want to send data without the names of the properties to not spend much bandwidth. I'm sending over 5000 objects with each object 40 properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me preface this by saying that I don't think it's a good idea, but you can use transformers to control how objects are serialized. However, if you use generated client libraries, you will lose all information--they will only see things as lists of strings. Endpoints should automatically gzip things for you, which should help save a lot of bandwidth. You should do measurements comparing the two full lists of 5000 and seeing how much bandwidth exactly is being saved. Keep in mind that Endpoints won't transmit empty properties either, so if the many properties aren't all set, you save bandwidth automatically.

See [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) for details on how to use transformers. Basically, you want a `class ItemTransformer implements Transformer<Item, List<String>>` with the relevant annotations.